# JSSOR slider - using $Align on thumbnails slides on different direction

Tags: javascript, jquery, jssor

I am using the JSSOR slider to show 4 items like a gallery (as in the http://www.jssor.com/demos/image-gallery-with-vertical-thumbnail.html example). Only difference is that I use $Lanes: 1 and $Cols: 3.
The idea is to show 1 item in the main area and 3 on the thumbnails area. It all works perfectly well.
However, I want these 3 "thumbnails" to be all the remaining except the one being shown in the main area. To do that, I set a value in $Align (for example, 100) but from a certain value on, the thumbnails stop moving bottom to up and start moving up to bottom. How do I keep the "direction" in which the thumbnails move? The indexes are all correct and the click takes the slider to the correct position but I really didnt want the thumbnails to move differently just by using the $Align.

Comment: It will look for the shortest distance to move the thumbnail of current slide to $ParkingPosition.

Comment: If that is the case, then we have no way to control the direction it moves, correct? It will move to what ever direction it decides is the best.
That being said, if you have a vertical slider ith the main area on top and the thumbnails below, its kinda strange seeing the main area sliding upwards and the thumbs sliding downwards. Can it not be altered? Like adding an optional field to control the direction?